403 Forbidden Error- Authorizing w/ Spotify API
I am currently trying to use the Spotify API with a React.js web application I want to make. However, I keep getting error 403 (forbidden) when I run the app. Any help is very greatly appreciated! Been stuck on this for a bit now.
I tried several different methods of making these endpoints, calling them, etc. I really just cannot seem to work around this. I'm not sure what I am missing
Here is the current code:
router.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';

  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));;
});

router.get('/callback', function(req, res){
  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
});


The code seems to be correct. Are you using a subscribed plan in your Spotify app, or you are using the free plan? If you're using the free plan, you'll need to subscribe for it to work properly.
